# Django Runtime Error while trying to run server

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to run my Django server via 'python manage.py runserver' on a github repository i cloned and always get this runtime error message:

> class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
>
> RuntimeError: ____class____ not set defining 'AbstractBaseUser' as <'class 'django.contrib.auth.base_user.AbstractBaseUser'>. Was ____classcell____ propagated to type.____new____?

Details of installed packages in my virtual environment are:
Django               1.9 |
django-crispy-forms  1.6.0 |
django-markdown-deux 1.0.5 |
django-pagedown      0.1.1 |
markdown2            2.3.1 |
olefile              0.46 |
Pillow               7.1.1 |
pip                  19.2.3 |
setuptools           41.2.0 |

I am using python version 3.8.1

please does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should try to update your packages to the latest versions, as you are using python 3.8. Check this also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django
I don't think Django 1.9 is compatible with python 3.8

Comment: I upgraded everthing to the latest libraries and made a few changees where necessary and it worked. tanx

Answer (score 0):

RuntimeError at /save
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/save/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.